# HTTP trigger does not return stacktrace in Azure Functions v2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Consider a simple HTTP trigger that throws an exception. When I make a call to this trigger via Postman, it return a 500 Internal Server Error, but the body is empty. As a developer, I want to see the stacktrace so that I can quickly debug what's going on.

```
// Azure Functions v2
[FunctionName("HttpTrigger2")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpTrigger2(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequestMessage req)
{
    throw new System.Exception("I want to be in the response body.");
}
```

This is run locally. I have not yet tested this remotely.

I believe Azure Functions v1 did show the stacktrace.

I know that there are various ways of inspecting the logs, e.g. by hooking up the environment to AppInsights. What I am looking for an immediate response from the server.

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain how the question could have been improved.

Comment: Hi Thomas, do you need further help? If the workaround is acceptable do you mind accepting the solution for others to refer?

Comment: Hi Jerry. I haven't tried it yet (other things came up). Once I tried, I will let you know. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be by design that v2 function doesn't return stack trace anymore like v1 does. And on remote Azure site, neither v1 nor v2 function returns stack trace. The design is reasonable, stack trace is used for debug while the response body is apparently not. With stack trace returned as response, we seem to expose lengthy and sometimes private info.

If we want to get exceptions as response for convenience while debugging locally, catch the exception and return it as response.

To work with `HttpRequestMessage`

```
        try
        {
            throw new System.Exception("I want to be in the response body.");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            log.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception);
        }
```

In v2, we also could use `HttpRequest` and the response type should be `IActionResult`.

```
        try
        {
            throw new System.Exception("I want to be in the response body.");
        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            log.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
            var res = new ObjectResult(exception)
            {
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError
            };
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: Now, the exception is not logged in the `exceptions` table of AppInsights. Is there a way to both log it in AI and the get it back as the response?

Comment: @ThomasSchreiter Simply add `log.LogError(exception, exception.Message);` before we send response back, don't forget to add [AI key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#appinsightsinstrumentationkey) in local.settings.json.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the env variable CLI_DEBUG to 1 in your machine to get full exceptions in local env, debugging etc